# How to separate the beans in classes different than the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am learinf spring boot, and i developed the belwo simple example. As shown, I am using two main annotaions @SpringApplication and @RestController.
When i use postman to run the webservice and to make communication between the backend and frontend via

```
http:://localhost:8080
```

I can have access to all the methods annotated with @RequestMapping

I would like to inquire about, how to split the controllers in another class. In other words, I do not want the Class that is annotated with @SpringApplication to contains any
classes annotated with @RequestMapping.

I want to have for example, two classes for GreetingText and Greeting respectively.

In the section **attempt** below is my attempts, but i receive the foloowing error:

```
    //Could not autowire no beans of string
```

Please let me know:

1-how to split "Greeting" and "GreetingText" in another classes so that I can call them as follwo:

```
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/GreetingText?
```

2- why when the Autowired is used i received the below posted error

```
    //Could not autowire no beans of string
```

**code**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class GreetingApplicationModelObject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GreetingApplicationModelObject.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String GreetingText() {
    return "Frontend Greeting";
}

@RequestMapping("/greetingWithParams")
public Greeting Greeting(@RequestParam(value = "val", defaultValue = "no_val_from_front-end") String val) {
    return new Greeting(getRandomValue(), val);
}

public int getRandomValue() {
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(1000);
}
```

}

**attempt**:

```
@Autowired
private String str;

//Could not autowire no beans of string
@Autowired
GreetingFromDeuController(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}

@Autowired
public String getGreetingFromDeu() {
    return this.str;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many `RestController` classes as you want.

```
@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String greetingText() {
        return "Greeting";
    }

}
```

These classes will be automatically picked up by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is 100% right, but to go into a little more detail with an answer to your question, beans are picked up from a component scan in your project.

Your `@SpringBootApplication` should be in the root package of your project, no beans should be defined in any parent package.

To define a bean that will be picked up by component scan there are a lot of class level annotations that will make a bean of that class.
Some of the common ones are

```
@Configuration   // application configurations
@Component       // a general bean that you can use anywhere in your project
@RestController  // one or more exposed API endpoints
@Service         // a service bean for business logic of the application
@Respository     // a data access bean
```

But there are several more.

One common thing I've seen is a package structure like below

```
com.test.spring
    MainApplication.java  <-- @SpringBootApplication
    controller
      GreetingController.java <-- @RestController
    config
      AppConfig.java  <-- @Configuration
    service
      GreetingService.java <-- interface, no component
      impl
          GreetingServiceImpl.java <-- @Service
    dao
       GreetingRepsository <-- @Repository
```

It seems like for your application you wouldn't need all of that, it's just an example

You can also create beans with methods to specify an implementation or things like that.  I've used things like this on previous

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public String activeProfile(@Value("{spring.profiles.active}" profile) {
        return profile;
    }
}
```

Baeldung is always a good resource: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-annotations